# MaxListenersExceededWarning when using socket.pipe recursively

Tags: node.js, sockets, recursion, memory-leaks

In my `Node.JS` app, I need to execute a `writer` function recursively over a TCP connection. This is how I'm doing it:

```
var net = require('net');
const commonConfig = require('../config.common')

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {

    let writer  = () => {
        socket.write(Date.now() + '\n\r')
        socket.pipe(socket)
        setTimeout(writer, 1000)
    }
    writer()
});

server.listen(commonConfig.TCP_PORT, commonConfig.TCP_ADDR);
```

However, I get the following warnings:

`(node:4497) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:4497) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 finish listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:4497) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 unpipe listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:4497) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:4497) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 data listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:4497) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:4497) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`

What are these caused by and how can I resolve these without breaking my functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into a similar problem recently with piping causing the max listeners warning. I am not using event listeners, but strictly piping the resources. When I add too many writable pipes to receive the data from the same source, such as `sourcePipe.pipe(writablePipe)`, nodejs gives the warning.

Launching my app with a **--trace-warnings** flag gives more details to tell me specifically where the problem is occurring, which is exactly the code where the piping is happening. `node --trace-warnings app.js`. Passing that flag to your app may help to give you more details about your problem.

```
(node:5676) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 data listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
at _addListener (events.js:281:19)
at Mp4Frag.addListener (events.js:298:10)
at Mp4Frag.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:775:35)
at Mp4Frag.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:638:7)
at Socket.socket.on (L:\WebstormProjects\ffmpeg-streamer\sockets\mse.js:83:33)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
at L:\WebstormProjects\ffmpeg-streamer\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:513:12
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

It points to line 83 of the mse.js file, which is `mp4frag.pipe(writable);`

I have been stumped by this because I know it is not because I have any unhandled listeners causing a memory leak. I suppose we are justified to increase the max listeners limit since we have done our due diligence.

On my source pipe, I added some code **`mp4frag.setMaxListeners(20);`**. Now, when I exceed that number, I get the warning 
*`MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 21 end listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`* which is telling me that my set value of **20** is being used.